# IntelliJ IDEA asking for IDEA_HOME to be set in project configuration files - IDEA_HOME is undefined

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition on Mac OS X is giving an error "IDEA_HOME is undefined."

It has a Fix It option. This brings up a dialog: 
Configure Path Variables - 
There are undefined path variables in project configuration files. 
In the dialog box, IDEA_HOME has no value

[image: Configure Path Variables dialog box with IDEA_HOME blank.]

I cannot find what IDEA_HOME is meant to be. Is it the base directory of the IntelliJ IDEA application? Is it the .idea directory for the project?

Comment: IDEA_HOME is a path variable used by the project you're trying to open. You should ask the person who configured the project about its intended meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks yole. Looking at the files IDEA_HOME was referring to in the .idea project xml files, I was able to determine that IDEA_HOME referred to the base application folder of IDEA on my computer.

`/Applications/"IntelliJ IDEA 13 CE 2.app"`

A useful expanation of what path variables are is here: 
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/path-variables.html

If you need to access path variables on Mac go to **IntelliJ IDEA > Preferences > Path Variables** (under the IDE Settings heading).